# upload video on youtube channel from my site

Tags: php, youtube, google-api

I am trying  to upload video on youtube channel from my site(created in php), without user authentication.  I am using  **"youtube v3 API"**.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/ 
Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication

But it requires user authentication for uploading.

Question1: Is there any way to upload video on youtube without user authentication?
Question2: I need to know how can we implement this by browser based uploading(i.e. upload directly on youtube server) ?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you cannot upload videos without user authentication.
2. It's not possible either. You need remote server so you could connect to YT.

Comment: Is any way to upload users video on my youtube channel by using my API credentials?

Comment: Yes, but you still need remote server, so video can be uploaded to your server, and from your server to YT.

Comment: @SachinGupta did you find solution? If yes, can you tell us how?